# python - could ioctl numbers differs from C ioctl numbers?

Tags: python, ioctl, fcntl

As far as I know, ioctl numbers are well defined by the drivers and registered in the kernel.

I was playing with some code in python for querying joystick states. I have read [this doc about joystick api](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/joystick-api.txt), [this doc about ioctl numbers](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl-number.txt), and [this one from python fcntl module](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html).

I've created a C program for testing and querying values, and the python tests with code that I took [from here](http://www.hsg-kl.de/faecher/inf/material/bonsai/util/ppdev.py) for implementing the `_IOR()` C macro.

### Kernel driver define:

```
monolith@monolith ~/temp $ grep JSIOCGAXES /usr/include/* -r
/usr/include/linux/joystick.h:#define JSIOCGAXES        _IOR('j', 0x11, __u8)
```

### C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/joystick.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {  
  int fd = open("/dev/input/js0", O_RDONLY);
  printf("Ioctl Number: (int)%d  (hex)%x\n", JSIOCGAXES, JSIOCGAXES);
  char number;
  ioctl(fd, JSIOCGAXES, &number);
  printf("Number of axes: %d\n", number);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

### C program Output:

```
monolith@monolith ~/temp $ ./test 
Ioctl Number: (int)-2147390959  (hex)80016a11
Number of axes: 6
```

### Python output

```
# check if _IOR results in the used ioctl number in C
>>> _IOR(ord('j'), 0x11, 'c')
-2147390959
>>> file = open("/dev/input/js0")
# use that integer
>>> fcntl.ioctl(file, -2147390959)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address
# ask what hex value is
>>> "%x" % -2147390959
'-7ffe95ef'
# WHY THIS HEX CONVERSION DIFFERS?
>>> fcntl.ioctl(file, -0x7ffe95ef)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address
# Use the hex value from the C program output
>>> fcntl.ioctl(file, 0x80016a11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Any ideas why I can't query the file descriptor with that ioctl number? `ioctl()` and `fcntl()` functions take a file descriptor or an object with the `fileno()` method implemented so I discart the error from the `file` object.

Maybe the problem comes with number conversion and types, no idea...clues?

Comment: Using `fcntl.fcntl()` I get this error: `OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum`. Now I need to know why C `ioctl()` is managing the argument correctly. C `ioctl()` takes an `int` as an argument. Would tracking the `int` offset be an approach to determine the `signed integer` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question.

For some reason, the only way to get the value using `ioctl()` from python was issuing this code:

```
>>> buf = array.array('h', [0])
>>> fcntl.ioctl(file.fileno(), 0x80016a11, buf)
0
>>> buf[0]
6
```

That is, using a buffer to sotre the result. I should re-read the documentation and understand why `fcntl.ioctl(file.fileno(), 0x80016a11)` was not working.

Comment: I might be absolutely wrong here, but I think it might be because the underlying ioctl system call does not return anything, instead it modifies a special struct (struct ifconf from net/if.h?) that you pass it. So probably python while using the underlying ioctl call needs to do that same.

Answer (score 2):

This all boils down to the hex conversions being different - plugging the hex C gives you into Python gives you a different number:

```
>>> 0x80016a11
2147576337
```

I'm not sure why Python and C give different hex, but it is likely at least partially related to sign - Python's `'%x'` gives a *signed* hex value [1](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), `printf`s gives unsigned [2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Using Python's hex value (`-7ffe95ef`) is likely to improve things - or, even better, use a variable like you do in C and keep the conversion errors out of it:

```
op = _IOR(ord('j'), 0x11, 'c')
...
fcntl.ioctl(file, op)
```

Comment: About different hex values: I think you are right. I have tested with some C code. In what my problem concerns, I haven't had luck. It seems there's a [bug with 64bit machines](http://bugs.python.org/issue1112949) but should be resolved for now on. Anyway, the proposed solution from the issue didn't work either.

Comment: [This bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1309352) has a newer date. Though, It doesn't seems to work for me.